# How to get a custom object out of a generic List with LINQ?

Tags: linq, ienumerable

Why do I get the following error in the following code?

I thought if I put custom objects in a generic List of its type then IEnumerable would be taken care of? What else do I need to do to this List to use LINQ on it?

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`<TestLinq23.Customer>`'
>   to 'TestLinq23.Customer'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestLinq23
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Customer> customerSet = new List<Customer>();
            customerSet.Add(new Customer { ID = 1, FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Smith" });
            customerSet.Add(new Customer { ID = 2, FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Douglas" });
            customerSet.Add(new Customer { ID = 3, FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Anders" });

            Customer customerWithIndex = customerSet[1];
            Console.WriteLine("Customer last name gotten with index: {0}", customerWithIndex.LastName);

            Customer customerWithLinq = from c in customerSet
                           where c.FirstName == "Joe"
                           select c;
            Console.WriteLine(customerWithLinq.LastName);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a call to [`Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) - otherwise it's returning a *sequence* of customers.

At the same time, there's no real need to use a query expression here. It'll be simpler to use dot notation:

```
Customer customerWithLinq = customerSet.Where(c => c.FirstName == "Joe")
                                       .Single();
```

In fact, you can make it even simpler, because there's an overload of `Single()` to take a predicate:

```
Customer customerWithLinq = customerSet.Single(c => c.FirstName == "Joe")
```

Is it an error condition if there isn't exactly one match? If not, you might want to use [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) instead of `Single()`.

EDIT: As pointed out by Garry, if there may be *no* results you might want [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) or [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx) - both of these will return `null` if no entries match.

Comment: May also need the *OrDefault() variants if it's valid for a record to not exist.

Comment: Yes, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Had also forgotten the overload taking a predicate - even simpler :)

Comment: Didn't know about the overload. Makes it just that little easier to read.